# Change background color of UIButton on UITableViewCell in section

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created the `UITableView` programatically, and in my `UITableView` have 3 rows in the `UITableView` section. I have a `UIButton` in 3 rows. Initially, all the buttons of three rows have gray color. If I select the button in the 2nd row, then the button in the 2nd row should be red and the all others gray and so on. Can any one suggest me.

Comment: You have only 1 section? Or multiple?

Comment: what do you mean by color? is it just text color,background color....pick one..

Comment: i have multiple section and each section have one row

Comment: not textcolor, i want to change button backgroundcolor @T_77

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:Your Frame];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag = indexPath.section;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Then write `buttonClicked` method

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    UIButton *but1;
    UIButton *but2;
    if (button.tag == 0)
    {
        but1 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
        but2 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
        [but1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [but2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    if (button.tag == 1)
    {
        but1 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
        but2 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
        [but1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [but2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    if (button.tag == 2)
    {
        but1 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
        but2 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
        [but1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [but2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: why do you mention 2 buttons in each block?

Comment: This will not work, he has multiple sections with 1 row. So each button will have tag 0

Comment: in my tableview, have more than 3 cells, its came from the services.

Comment: you can use for loop there.

Comment: can you plz give more clarity on loop @ Pradumna Patil

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create the button as mentioned by patil (look below for his answer) ,and try to give it a tag.

```
     button.tag=indexpath.section;

You need to set target-action of each button.Write the following line in the button action method:

   [button setTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then implement someMethod: like this:

```
  - (void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender {
if (sender.tag == 1) {
    // do action for button with tag 1
     //change color here
  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

} else if (sender.tag == 2) {
    // do action for button with tag 2
} // ... and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too fond of the multiple `if` cases as you would need to re-write a lot when your amount of `sections` / `rows` change.

This is a more generic answer but it might not be so easy as the others. It involves created a `UIButton` subclass and a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Create a `UIButton` subclass with a property to store the `NSIndexPath` of the cell where the button will be shown on:

```
//
//  IndexPathButton.h
//
//
//  Created by You on 28/07/15.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IndexPathButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@end
```

There should not be anything implemented in the .m file.

Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass which has the custom `IndexPathButton` on it. If you need help creating a custom `UITableViewCell` I suggest [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search) on SO or [creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question.

In your `UIViewController` with your `UITableView` do the import of the custom `UIButton`

```
#import "IndexPathButton.h"
```

Also create an class variable to store the selectedIndexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedButtonIndexPath;
```

Now we can start changing the `UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"SomeCell";
    YourCustomCellWithButton *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[YourCustomCellWithButton alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    //Default setup of IndexPathButton on YourCustomCellWithButton
    cell.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.button.indexPath = indexPath; //Here we store the indexPath for later use
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Check here if it should be red or not
    if (selectedButtonIndexPath == indexPath)
    {
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And the button target action:

```
-(void)cellButtonPressed:(IndexPathButton*)sender
{
    //Set the selectedIndexPath
    selectedButtonIndexPath = sender.indexPath;
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```